# encoding mp3 or other music files

Tags: c#, audio, mp3

a bit of background:
this summer, i set myself a programming project,
where i want to make an E-jay clone(a program with simple drag-drop blocks which are little bits of music and beat to make a track)
now i dont really know where to start on the whole encoding music bit.
for example:
how does a sound file work?
how do i transform a piece of a sound file into a universal piece of sound information
how do i create a sound file from scratch
how do i add pieces of sound to a previously newly created sound file

im sorry if i seem like one of those guys that cant use google n stuff. but i have no experience with sound or anything on that part.

programming language: C#
ultimate goal: be able to encode a new mp3 file using small sound files which are inserted on certain points in the file to ultimatly make music

any help is appreciated,
thank you for reading my question.

Comment: I suggest you dig into DirectX from the beginning, since you will soon run into limits when playing multiple samples at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) site - it has lots of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Do some research into the MPEG compression standard, as you'll need to know about decoding as well as encoding. If you are going to be ambitious, maybe look into other audio file types as well.

MP3 Links:
[MP3 Format](http://mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/MP3Format.html)
[ISO Draft on the MPEG standard](http://cutebugs.net/files/mpeg-drafts/11172-3.pdf)